# Android: How to embed an Image in another imageview?

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I have an air condition image, now I want to show it's brand name(another image) in the right top corner, and current temperature (image too) in the center. Is there a convenient way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `RelativeLayout`, which allows you to overlays views over each other. You can read more about RelativeLayouts [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

This is an example of how you could use a RelativeLayout, although you will have to adjust it for you as you didn't post any of your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagef"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ph_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```